# This query in Linq to Sql

Tags: linq-to-sql

i have in my DB table TBus fields like s1,s2.s3.s4,...sn
i get the seatNumber as a parameter and want to get that field just like i have it in my code.
Any idea please.

```
private string checkSeatValue(int busTripId, int seatNumber)
{
    string sNumber = "s" + seatNumber.ToString();
    // Some code here

    string sqlCommand = "SELECT " + sNumber + " FROM TBus WHERE Id=" + busTripId + "";
    // More code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want pure Linq2SQL code, you should get the TBus object:

```
var bus = yourDataContext.GetTable<TBus>().Where(bus => bus.BusTripId == busTripId).SingleOrDefault();
```

And then switch your seat variable to get the desired field:

```
var seat;

switch(seatNumber)
{
    case "s1":
        seat = bus.Seat1;
        break;
    case "s2":
        seat = bus.Seat2;
        break;
    // And so it goes on...
}
```

However, you can do pure SQL code via Linq also or play with reflection.

-- EDIT

As I said in the comment, I believe your database model can be improved. My advice would be having two tables:

**TBus Table**

```
TBusId - int [PK]
...
```

**TBusSeat Table**

```
TBusSeatId - int [PK]
TBusIs - int [FK referencing TBus.TBusId]
SeatNumber - int
...
```

That way, you have more natural flexibility to deal with those king of situations. Consider the following set of data:

**TBus Table**

```
TBusId
------
1
2
```

**TBusSeat Table**

```
TBusSeatId | TBusId | SeatNumber | PassengerName
------------------------------------------------
1            1        1            Josh Doe
2            1        2            John Doe
3            1        3            Jane Doe
4            2        1            Jack Doe
```

So, to deal with your desired query with Linq2SQL, it would be simple as this:

```
var seat = yourDataContext.GetTable<TBusSeat>().Where(seat => seat.TBusId == 1 && seat.SeatNumber == 2).SingleOrDefault();
```

And calling `seat.PassengerName` would result in `John Doe`.

Comment: And IMHO, your database model is messed up. It would be more flexible if you had a `TBusSeat` Table.

Comment: hello EvertonAgner.. what you mean by a TBusSeat Table..? in each bus there is 54 seat, how can you do that..? by creating 54 tables.? that is missed up.

Comment: No, my friend. My advice would be having two Tables: `TBus` and `TBusSeat`. See my edit for more details.